# Export NFS share to all IP addresses

Tags: freebsd

This is my current `/etc/exports` on my freeBSD machine

```
/shared -alldirs 177.16.8.77
```

how do I share `/shared` with all IPs and not just `177.16.8.77` ?

Comment: Just remove the IP address. If you do not specify an address, it is shared with the world.

Answer (score 0):

From `man exports` (available on Debian Linux, I would be surprised if it's not on freeBSD):

```
Machine Name Formats
   NFS clients may be specified in a number of ways:
   [...]
   wildcards
          Machine names may contain the wildcard characters * and ?, or
          may contain character class lists within [square brackets].
          This can be used to make  the  exports  file  more   compact;
          for instance, *.cs.foo.edu matches all hosts in the domain
          cs.foo.edu. As these characters also match the dots in a
          domain name, the given pattern will also match all hosts
          within any subdomain of cs.foo.edu.
```

So use `*` to export a directory to all possible hosts. Perhaps omitting the host specification altogether will work on freeBSD, according to some sources.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean *all* IPs? Not very secure!

To share with your network, do it like this:

```
/shared -alldirs -network 177.16.0.0/16
```

or

```
/shared -alldirs -network 177.16.0.0 -mask 255.255.0.0
```